# How to change the shell being used from Dash (or sh) to Bash during script execution?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

Say there's a script that makes use of a certain Bash feature, like arrays. But say that script is being run using `sh` on Ubuntu, which is Dash, a shell that does not support arrays. Let's also assume I can't control which shell is being used from the get go, i.e. I'm stuck with Dash to start the script with.

Is it possible to detect and switch away from Dash (or any other shell) to Bash, assuming the location of Bash binary is known and can be safely assumed to be consistent? E.g. I run the following script using `sh myscript.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Do something here to detect Dash and switch to Bash (/bin/bash)

my_array=(yay i can use arrays now)

# ...
```

Please note that the script **must** be run using `sh myscript.sh` and I cannot update it to make it `bash myscript.sh`.

Comment: Have a look at the `-c` option, e.g. `bash -c '...'`

Comment: @Jetchisel I'm aware of `bash -c`, great for one liners, not-so-great for entire scripts. @pynexj Without getting too into it, I don't have that luxury. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: @Sumit, you can have newlines when using `bash -c'...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash always sets `BASH_VERSION`. You can check if it's set and restart the script with bash otherwise like this:

```
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  exec bash "$0" "$@"
fi

my_array=(yay i can use arrays now)

# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't fight the system: Since according to your posting you **know** that in this context, the call will be `sh myscript.sh` - i.e. the caller assumes that you have a sh script here - write it as tiny *sh* script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is myscript.sh
/path/to/your/bash /path/to/your/myscript.bash "$@"
```

Your real bash-code is then in `myscript.bash`, where you can use arrays and other bash goodies.

This design also lets you to eventually switch to other languages (zsh, ruby,...), if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current used shell in your script with following command:

```
ps -p $$ -o exe=
```

The output of this command should be something like "/usr/bin/bash".
As Jetchisel already mentioned, force a command to use the bash shell, use it like this:

```
bash -c SOME_COMMAND
```

You can also use a shebang on the top of the file to use the specific shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

some commands
```

and call your script with ./my_script.bash. Make sure your script is executable.